# How to set text dynamically in unreal engine

Tags: c++, json, unreal-engine4

I would like to set text and 2d images dynamically in Unreal Engine maybe using a placeholder like a Billboard Blueprint then using the Set Text Blueprint.

I am getting json from an external source -- amazon product information -- then want to update the UI Billboard with this json result which includes text and links to image files.

Does anyone know how to achieve this.

Comment: Please show us some code on what do you have so far, and possibly what you think the issue may be.

Comment: Unreal4 online documentation would tell you better than you what to use. We can help you only on a precise issue.

Answer (score 1):

Create the string:

```
FString TestHUDString = FString(TEXT("Buy this crap!"));
```

FStrings can be set/modified during runtime just like you want it from a std::string

```
TestHUDString = "buy this other crap....";
```

And (for example) write it to the "screen":

```
Canvas->DrawText(BigFont, TestHUDString, 110.0f,110.0f);
```

You man need to convert your data to a c string or UTF-8 if you have Problems.

Theres also text components of objects if you want to create "in world" billboards for example.

Here the official documentation about using FStrings:

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/StringHandling/FString/

This should help assuming that you know how to deserialize the json - wich is a different topic imho.

Comment: Which "text components of objects" do you mention? I tried with ATextRenderActor, but it's not always facing the camera (like Billboards do). I tried rotating them with `Text->SetActorRotation(FRotationMatrix::MakeFromX(CameraLocation - ObjectLocation).Rotator());` but it's not like how OGRE's billboards looked like, sometimes the text goes upside down, etc.

Comment: I think a [UTextRenderComponent](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UTextRenderComponent/index.html) inside a Scene component should do it.Then you transform/rotate the SCENE COMPONENT!. [Here a blueprint example of the logic you need to rotate](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/30596-3d-widget-that-always-faces-the-player-camera) This defenitely works. I used this with a widget in the scene component but it doesnt matter whats in it.

Comment: I tried that, it compiles, but nothing is showing on screen. Can you provide an example, please? Someone also said that UTextRender can be rotated without the need for a Scene.